# Kotlin - Error with SAM Interface (Android Routing Cicerone)

Tags: kotlin

I started using the library for routes in an android application. There was such a problem, I don't know how to solve it.

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
    Creator<Context, Intent>
Found:
    () → Intent
```

Library used Cicerone. I created my object class Screens and according to some sources made an implementation like this

```
import com.csproject.rflex.app.App
import com.csproject.rflex.presentation.launch.LaunchActivity
import com.github.terrakok.cicerone.androidx.ActivityScreen

object Screens {

    fun launch() = ActivityScreen {
         LaunchActivity.newIntent(App.instance.getAppContext())
    }

}
```

Activity code fragment

```
class LaunchActivity: ABaseActivity(), ILaunchView {

    companion object{
        fun newIntent(context: Context) = Intent(context, LaunchActivity::class.java)
    }
```

Libriry class

```
sealed class AppScreen : Screen

fun interface Creator<A, R> {
    fun create(argument: A): R
}

open class FragmentScreen @JvmOverloads constructor(
    private val key: String? = null,
    private val fragmentCreator: Creator<FragmentFactory, Fragment>
) : AppScreen() {
    override val screenKey: String get() = key ?: super.screenKey
    fun createFragment(factory: FragmentFactory) = fragmentCreator.create(factory)
}

open class ActivityScreen @JvmOverloads constructor(
    private val key: String? = null,
    private val intentCreator: Creator<Context, Intent>
) : AppScreen() {
    override val screenKey: String get() = key ?: super.screenKey
    open val startActivityOptions: Bundle? = null
    fun createIntent(context: Context) = intentCreator.create(context)
}
```

---

*UPDATE #1*
I modified the code a bit, but I'm not sure if it should work this way

```
fun launch(context: Context) = ActivityScreen (intentCreator = object: Creator<Context, Intent> {
        override fun create(argument: Context): Intent {
            return MainActivity.newIntent(context)
        }
    })
```

It works, but I think you can do it differently

Comment: Please include the line of code that produces the error.

Comment: `ActivityScreen { LaunchActivity.newIntent(App.instance.getAppContext()) }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your lambda is getting its context externally rather than from a lambda argument, so its signature doesn't match the signature of your interface.

Try this:

```
ActivityScreen { LaunchActivity.newIntent(it) }
```

If it isn't able to infer the context from that, I guess you would need:

```
ActivityScreen { context: Context -> LaunchActivity.newIntent(context) }
```

Comment: First way 
`Type mismatch.
Required:
Creator<Context, Intent>
Found:
() → Intent
Unresolved reference: it`
Second way
`Type mismatch.
Required:
Creator<Context, Intent>
Found:
(Context) → Intent `

Comment: Is the library publicly available? I'd like to take a look

Comment: ,I found a solution, see the updated question, I edited it. But I'm not sure if this is true

Comment: That's how to do it the anonymous function way and perfectly fine, just verbose. Actually, I can't reproduce your problem, even using your original code. Are you sure you're using Kotlin 1.4? SAM conversion for Kotlin interfaces was not added until Kotlin 1.4.